# Что производительнее и экономнее, копия функции через bind или функция обертка

Tags: javascript, node.js, функции, оптимизация

На сервере есть код вэбсокета вида:

```
wss.on('connect', function (ws, request) {
  const socketData = {
    login: 'krakazyabra'
  }
  
  ws.on('close', function () {
    // какой то код
    console.log(`Пользователь ${socketData.login} отключился`);
    // и еще код
  }
}
```

хочу вынести функцию закрытия соединения во вне, однако функция использует внешнюю переменную `socketData`.

Получаем следующий код функции закрытия соединения. Т.е. теперь в функцию надо передать переменную **socketData**

```
function closeConnect (socketData) {
  // какой то код
  console.log(`Пользователь ${socketData.login} отключился`);
  // и еще код
}
```

Вот 2 варианта, которые у меня получились, но оба не очень нравятся, возможно, есть И-й вариант?

###### Через .bind

```
wss.on('connect', function (ws, request) {
  const socketData = {
    login: 'krakazyabra'
  }
  
  ws.on('close', closeConnect.bind(null, socketData));
})
```

###### Через функцию обертку

```
wss.on('connect', function (ws, request) {
  const socketData = {
    login: 'krakazyabra'
  }
  
  ws.on('close', function () {
      closeConnect(socketData)
    });
})
```

**Вопрос:** Как более правильно и читаемо сделать с точки зрения производительности и экономии памяти, через .bind или фукнцию обертку?

На сколько я понимаю, bind будет для каждого соединения создавать новую функцию и держать ее в памяти. 100 пользователей, 100 копий фукнции. В то же время, фукнция обертка смотрится не очень.

Comment: обертка через bind не совсем настоящая функция, но на сколько она отличается по памяти/быстродействию непонятно. Попробуй какой-нибудь benchmark сделать

Comment: Ты функцию `closeConnect` не можешь менять?

Comment: @ksa я могу менять все.

Comment: _для каждого соединения создавать новую функцию и держать ее в памяти_ - пока все варианты в том или ином виде создают функцию и держат ее в памяти просто за счет того что они должны брать данные для коннекта специфичные

Comment: @Grundy я считал, что если в обработчик передается готовая функция, то обработчик, уссловно, ссылается на нее, а не создает копию фукнции при каждом навешивании события. А вот bind как раз создает новую функцию, но вот под капотом не понятно, это та же функция, но с внутренней оберткой или целиком новая фукнция(полная копия исходной + параметры из bind'a).

Comment: [Why is bind slower than a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17638305/2881286)

Comment: _я считал, что если в обработчик передается готовая функция, то обработчик, уссловно, ссылается на нее, а не создает копию фукнции при каждом навешивании события_ - чтобы тебе передать аргументы в твою одну функцию - тебе в любом случае нужно сделать дополнительную функцию - либо через bind, либо с замыканием. Создание новой функции остается. `Bind` не копирует функцию

Comment: *"с точки зрения производительности и экономии памяти"* будет правильнее реализовать все это на языке с возможностью ручного управления памятью. При использовании js вы не управляете памятью и не заботитесь о производительности. Использование bind и оберток в вашем случае примерно эквивалентны, так как в обоих случаях происходит эквивалентные связывания со внешним по отношению к функции объектом.